# Sql query not returning all results

Tags: c#, sql, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I'm using an OLEDB Command to run a basic query on a .mdb file like so:

```
    List<TPRItem> itemList = new List<TPRItem>();
    string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dirPath;
    string sql = "SELECT UPC, ItemDesc, TPRAllow, NetCost, UnitCost, Pack, TPREndDate FROM OrderGuide WHERE TPRAllow > 0";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                        TPRItem thisTPRItem = new TPRItem();
                        thisTPRItem.UPC = rdr["UPC"].ToString();
                        thisTPRItem.VendorDescription = rdr["ItemDesc"].ToString();
                        thisTPRItem.CaseAllowance = decimal.Parse(rdr["TPRAllow"].ToString());
                        thisTPRItem.CaseCost = decimal.Parse(rdr["NetCost"].ToString());
                        thisTPRItem.UnitCost = decimal.Parse(rdr["UnitCost"].ToString());
                        thisTPRItem.CsPack = int.Parse(rdr["Pack"].ToString());
                        thisTPRItem.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["TPREndDate"].ToString());
                        thisTPRItem.CaseAllowanceCost = thisTPRItem.CaseCost - thisTPRItem.CaseAllowance;
                        thisTPRItem.UnitAllowanceCost = thisTPRItem.CaseAllowanceCost / thisTPRItem.CsPack;
                        itemList.Add(thisTPRItem);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Only 2365 items are added to my list. However when I run this exact same query in Access I get 10867 results.

I am accessing a .mdb file that changes from month to month (the data changes not the format) and previously we have not had issues with missing items.

Comment: Add a counter in the while loop so you can see how many are actually read.  You know 2365 are inserted but you don't really know how many you read.  You need to show the code inside the while loop for us to determine why the insert may be failing.

Comment: I've added the code for adding the items, I should also note that I have this in a try catch block and am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: @Las I have added a counter to my while loop and can confirm that I am only reading 2365 rows.

Comment: What version of access are you using?  You are using the Jet Engine which is for Office 2003 and older that has limitations on number of rows in the database.  The ACE driver is used with Office 2007 and later which can handle larger databases.  So change the connection string.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code.  I'd try stepping through the code.  I'd also reduce the query result set to a handful of rows and then gradually add records to see where they start to get dropped.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any exception during while loop execution? @user9357569

Comment: @jdweng I believe .mdb is for 2003 and older. I tried using this connection string: @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dirPath +";"; and am getting the same result.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya My try catch block is not catching any exceptions.

Comment: What is the rest of the method? I can't see a return statement. Show all the way up to where you determine the list count. And as a sanity check, make sure your connection string is pointed to the same database that you are manually querying through the Acess UI.

Comment: If you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderGuide WHERE TPRAllow > 0` from your application, what is returned?

Comment: I don't see a `itemList.Save` anywhee but I guess you must have one somewhere.

Comment: There is a property for each table that contains the version of Office the table was created with.  When you upgrade to a new version of office the create version doesn't always change.  Don't know the rules for ACCESS.  In Excel it doesn't usually change so you can have a workbook with multiple versions of worksheets.  Access is the front end of the database.  The real database is the driver either Jet or ACE. So when you are doing a query from ACCESS it should be the same as using oledb.Are you doing the query on the same PC using ACCESS and c#?  If it is different PCs then Jet is different.

Comment: It may be the c# project properties.  Are you using x86 or AnyCPU?  There are different versions of Jet in the c:\windows folder depending if you are using 32 bit or 64 bit.  The JET files look like msjet40.dll in the windows folder.  On my PC I have two 1) 7/1/17 - 64 bit 4.0.9801.1 2) 7/13/2009 - 32 bit 4.0.9756.0

Comment: Just found there are oledb versions as well : msjetoledb40.dll

Comment: You may be timing out :             cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;  //default is 30 seconds increase to 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Change your provider to a higher version.